# How can a vampire get around their sunlight vulnerability?

Tags: pathfinder-2e

A player of mine would like to play a [vampire](https://2e.aonprd.com/Archetypes.aspx?ID=181) and thus would get a vulnerability to sunlight (*Book of the Dead*, p. 58):

> If exposed to direct sunlight, you immediately become slowed 1. The slowed value increases by 1 each time you end your turn in sunlight. If you lose all your actions in this way, you are destroyed. Due to your supernatural aversion to light, you don't cast shadows or show a reflection in mirrors.

However, over half the (book) adventure is going to take place outside of dungeons and instead inside a busy town and a grass area and forest area – and naturally, not during the night (as you can't get into or out of town during that time).

Are there any ways to go around this sensitivity (levels 2-3)? For example, would thick clothing sealed by tar (and a hood brought very deep over the face and looking down permanently) be enough to avoid these negative effects?

Or are there other ways that can work to avoid the consequences of this sunlight vulnerability?

Comment: @AnneAunyme didnt think there are multiple oens.  Its the vampire archetype one from book of the dead

Comment: Is there a reason they won't be able to skulk around at night? I see "busy town and a grass area and forest area" and the only thing I can think of is that like shops close during the night. There doesn't seem to be any reason they couldn't leave/return during the night, or why some/many/most of the social encounters couldn't happen during dusk. Granted, some events may require the party be at X place during Y timeframe, but a lot of player agency involves choosing *when* to do things, and doing things "between sunset and sunrise" is only invalid for some of it

Answer (score 6):

### This is unlikely that there is one in the official rules

Being weak to sunlight is assumed to be one of the core points of being a vampire. The typical way to prevent it (partially) is [Daywalker](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=3549), a lvl 6 feat. A thick cloth is unlikely to be enough although I have to admit the rules aren't clear here, so it might work.

### As a DM, you can give anything to your player

You can decide to interpret the rules as "thick clothing is enough to protect you", or that it needs to be alchemically reinforced, or pretty much any ruling as long as it makes sense to you and your players.

You could also let them find a magic item that protects against sunlight, or earn a boon from a divinity. It doesn't have to be a flat negation of the vulnerability: maybe the vampire loses all their powers while in the light, or maybe the protection only lasts a few hours per day, or they are slowed while in the light. The only limit here is how to integrate it properly in your campaign so that it doesn't feel like a lazy cheat code but rather like an awesome reward.

Comment: As written, I think Daywalker would end up with the Vampire becoming paralyzed in the sun (essentially), since they'd still reach Slowed 3. I'd just houserule it to cap the Slowed at Slowed 2.

Comment: Becoming slowed 3 and needing someone to bring them back into the darkness before they can act again seems like a fine outcome to me

Answer (score 3):

### Avoid Direct Sunlight

The only guidance from the rules is that this vulnerability triggers on exposure to "direct sunlight", so any scheme that prevents direct sunlight from contacting the vampire should protect them.

Blocking out direct sunlight with heavy clothing and/or by only traveling within something like a coffin/carriage/coffin-inside-a-carriange would probably be good ideas, or otherwise following the safest strategy of only venturing outside during the night.

Answer (score 3):

## It is as much of a problem as *you* want it to be

There are several solutions, with different amounts of work and control for you as the DM. Here are some **examples**.

### Handwave

You say it is not a problem. It could be as simple as a wide brimmed hat.

Pros:

- Simple to remember
- No work for you

Cons:

- Anticlimactic
- Other players might resent it, if they think the archetype is too strong without it<sup>1</sup>

### Permanent item

The ***Hood of Shadow*** covers all of the face, but impairs vision. The vampire has a -1 status penalty to all checks and DCs, but does not have to wear it all the time (see *Direct sunlight is rare*). It takes an Interact action to engage or disengage it. Enemies can remove it with a successful Athletics check<sup>2</sup>.

Pros:

- You can combine getting it with a sidequest
- It still feels like a price to pay<sup>3</sup> for the extra power, but not crippling, like it was before

Cons:

- It can feel tedious engaging and disengaging it after a time

### Consumable item

The ***Suncream of Nyarlathotep*** protects the vampire completely, but it is costly, and lasts only X hours<sup>4</sup>. It takes an action to apply it.

Pros:

- You can combine getting the formula with a sidequest
- You control the supply (the ingredients might not be available in the wilderness / small village / etc)
- It can be as cheap or expensive as you see fit, you can even keep changing the price, see above
- It still feels like a price to pay<sup>5</sup> for the extra power, but not crippling, like it was before

Cons:

- It can feel tedious applying it after a time
- *You* have to deal with the supply constantly

## How I would handle it

This archetype is on the weaker side even without *sunlight sensitivity*.
I would just require some heavy clothing and gloves even in hot weather, and handwave the rest.

## *Direct* sunlight is rare

Most fantasy **towns** are modelled on medieval old towns. The streets are narrow, the buildings are not *that* low. This means lots of shadows, except for high noon, or the town square.

**Forests** are similar, it is not dark, but *direct* sunlight is rare.

**Open fields** provide no shade. Unless *you* offer some solution, they have to wait until sunset or avoid these areas alltogether.

---

1. it is not, even without sunlight sensitivity I am not sure it is worth a class feat, unless you are playing an undead heavy campaing, where negative damage and death effects are very common
2. just to keep it exciting. You can easily remove this part, if it feels too harsh
3. the actions to spend and the penalty are the price
4. they might need it during exploration too, so it should not be minutes. I would not make it last more than 1 hour, so they have to decide if they use it or not
5. the actions to spend are the price, plus the actual gold

Comment: Great answer! The DM can even remove direct sunlight with bad weather. On the player side, the smokestick is a cheap consumable that could buy some time in a pinch.